# Incentived Retagging

Tags: feature-request, tags

One thing that I've noticed with StackOverflow is organization is a big priority of the site, however there is little incentive to retag items. There is a badge for the first retagging, however there is no incentive to continue.

My suggestion: 
This is very similar to the image tagging problem in computer vision. (Applying appropriate and correct tags to large collections of images). This was solved by using the ESP Game and comparing the results of the tags with others' reactions. [Google uses this to tag images.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Image_Labeler)

I think this would be pretty cool, and would solve the issue with organization and tags.

Comment: +1 for "incentivize", but I don't think we need a special game.  Just make badges and let people retag as part of their normal activity on a site.

Comment: Retagging is now just another way to edit. As a sub-2000 rep user (on StackOverflow) I can only suggest edits. Lately I have suggested some retags -- when accepted, I get 2 points each. But I guess once I cross the 2000 threshold I will be allowed to make edits, but I won't get points for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried that Google game. It's quite fun! I think this sounds like a great idea!

Comment: You also aided google in indexing their photos!

Answer (score 1):

There is [another badge for retagging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white).

Comment: Thats for edits only. (Which requires a high reputation)

Comment: @steven: it was established a back while that retagging *is* editing in the eyes of the system.

Comment: I had no idea that it counted.

Comment: I thought that tag-edits **don't** count towards S+W???

Comment: @Marc - I've seen both statements, so I don't know which is correct any more.

Comment: @ChrisF: May be Jeff could chime in on this one?

Answer (score -2):

Badges aren't really much of an incentive here, rep is king.

(In fact, I've seen people get flamed for targetting a badge with a question, lol!)

Comment: Haha, how so? Asking a trick question and answering it himself?