# Have the rules changed for when a suggested edit provides +2 rep?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

AFAIK, When a user suggests an edit, he gets +2 reputation if the edit is approved. But if the suggested edit was only to *add or modify tags* it doesn't award +2 reputation. I recently saw this [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1822213). The user has only added a tag. The suggested edit got approved and [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1669234/tristan2468?tab=reputation) got +2 reputation.

Is it true that now user gets +2 for adding/modifying tags ?

I have already read this answer [How Suggested Edit works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/173001) but didnt found the answer.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [Incentivise retagging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169888/incentivise-retagging)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The +2 rep disappears for retags once you get the retag privilege (500 rep). Retags when you're above 500 don't go through the review system, and don't generate reputation.

Below 500 rep, the retag suggestion goes through review, and generates reputation when approved.

Comment: Thanks, Till now I was thinking that Adding/modifying tags doesn't generate +2 reputation.